# Why does my StreamWriter Response output produce garbage accents in Excel but look fine in Notepad?

Tags: asp.net, excel, character-encoding, response, streamwriter

I'm using a technique from [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008810/write-a-file-on-the-fly-to-the-client-with-c) to write a CSV file to the `Response` output for a User to Open/Save. The file looks good in Notepad, but when I open it in Excel the accented characters are garbage. I assumed this was something to do with the character encoding, so I tried manually setting it to UTF-8 (the default for `StreamWriter`). Here is the code:

```
// This fills a list to enumerate - each record is one CSV line
List<FullRegistrationInfo> fullUsers = GetFullUserRegistrations();

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                           "attachment; filename=registros.csv");
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.Charset = "utf-8";

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fullUsers.Count(); i++)
    {
        // Get the record to process
        FullRegistrationInfo record = fullUsers[i];

        // If it's the first record then write header
        if (i == 0)
            writer.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()) + 
                "User, First Name, Surname");

        writer.WriteLine(record.User + "," +
                         record.FirstName + "," +
                         record.Surname);
    }
}

context.Response.End();
```

Any ideas as to what else I would need to do to correctly encode the file so Excel can view the accented characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have to write an UTF-8 indicator called [Byte-order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) to the beginning of the output to notify Excel about the UTF-8ness. Silly Excel.

Comment: Thanks Ron! I used Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble()) to write this out at the start of the file, worked a treat then.