# ASP.NET web application create txt file on users computer

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp.net c# web application. On one of the pages i have a button and when pressed I want it to create a text file with certain text and save it to the users PC. I do not want to save it on the server or anything.

I Currently have this which writes 'test' to a file:

```
string fileLoc = "filePath";
            FileStream fs = null;
            fs = File.Create(fileLoc);

            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileLoc);
            sw.WriteLine("test");

            fs.Close();
            sw.Close();
```

How do I get it to save to the users computer.

Thanks for the help!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Asp.net write file to client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client)

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008810/write-a-file-on-the-fly-to-the-client-with-c-sharp?tab=oldest

Comment: So there is no way of saving it to the PC without it popping up and asking them to save? I need to access some data on the page like a label text and use it in a vba macro which is local.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET run on the server. If you would like to work with the client's computer you'll do it in Java Script. I recommend you to use any open source project written in javascript like this one https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return it trough an action method.

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(){
 return File(filePath, "text/plain", "MyFileName");
}
```

You cannot explicitly save it to the users PC because you simply don't have access to that. Returning it as an `ActionResult` (more specifically: `FileResult`) will return it as a download.

Comment: I don't think the OP is using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Possibly, yeah. I'll remove the answer and vote to close as duplicate if it turns out to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save the file directly in the client. You must write it into a Response, and then send it back to the client as a Download. There's a lot of ways, one of those include write the file stream directly into the Response like:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=yourfile.txt");
```

Reference: [C# Asp.net write file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072814/c-sharp-asp-net-write-file-to-client)